# SUBQUERY and EXISTS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running following query and it returns all columns in resultset from both `tblFamily` and `tblConstituent`.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblFamily AS f
WHERE
    DataProviderID = 23
    AND ISNULL(UsesIndexMarker, 0) = 0
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM tblConstituent
                WHERE FamilyID = f.FamilyID
                  AND StartDate < GETDATE()
                  AND EndDate > GETDATE()
                  AND FilterValue LIKE '%-%-%');
```

Now, I want only selected/few columns in the resultset from `tblFamily` and `tblConstituent` as below. But when I run I can fetch columns from `tblFamily` fine but can't fetch any of the columns from `tblConstituent`.

```
SELECT
    td.FamilyID, 
    td.Name,
    td.DataProviderID,
    td.UsesIndexMarker,
    td.OpenDate,
    td.ListingID
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM tblFamily AS f
     WHERE DataProviderID = 23
       AND ISNULL(UsesIndexMarker, 0) = 0
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM tblConstituent AS tc
                   WHERE tc.FamilyID = f.FamilyID
                     AND tc.StartDate < GETDATE()
                     AND tc.EndDate > GETDATE()
                     AND tc.FilterValue LIKE '%-%-%'
                     AND f.DataProviderID = 23
                     AND ISNULL(f.UsesIndexMarker, 0) = 0)) AS td;
```

Any idea why I can't fetch data from `tblConstituent` while all data is available when I run first query? I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 79
>   Invalid column name 'ListingID'

Hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

PS: Table Definitions below:

**tblFamily**

```
FamilyID    int
RefFamilyID int
FamilyTypeID    int
Name    varchar
DataProviderID  int
CalendarID  int
TrustedPrices   tinyint
FXRateSetID int
CurrentDate date
LastRevision    bigint
HasClose    tinyint
HasOpen tinyint
HasTPlus    tinyint
OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate   tinyint
PriceSetID  int
DividendSetID   int
CorporateActionSetID    int
IncludeFilterInNaturalKey   tinyint
MatchAllCodes   tinyint
CodeReferenceFamilyID   int
LatestTaskRunID int
TrustedFXRates  tinyint
HasDividends    tinyint
HasPrices   tinyint
HasRebalance    tinyint
HasReferenceData    tinyint
HasIntradayChanges  tinyint
TplusDataIsDelta    tinyint
ValidateAfterPersisting tinyint
LastUpdate  datetime
FundProviderID  int
TimeDataExpires time
ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits    bit
PrefilterConstituents   bit
LimitEndDate    bit
IgnoreForPricing    bit
ExcludedAssetSetID  int
NextRebalanceDate   date
TaxRateSetID    int
OpenDataIsDelta bit
RebalanceDataIsDelta    bit
OpenDate    date
AutoAddMissingListing   bit
EnforcedSecurityTypeID  int
TplusDataIsCummulative  bit
CalculationSetID    int
ValidationSetID int
UsesIndexMarker bit
MappingReferenceFamilyID    int
DataExtractionSetID int
MappingReferenceSecurityID  int
AutoAddOddLots  bit
DefaultFilterValue  varchar
SecurityClassID int
CountryClassificationID int
DataStatusMask  int
RebalanceFrequency  varchar
RebalanceNotes  varchar
NextRebalanceDataAvailable  date
CheckFileDates  bit
IsPayDateUseForReinvestment int
ValidationThresholdSetID    int
Created datetime
```

and table **tblConstituent**

```
ConstituentID   bigint
FamilyID    int
ListingID   int
StartDate   date
EndDate date
FilterValue varchar
ConstituentType tinyint
NumberOfUnits   decimal
PriceAdjustmentFactor   decimal
Factor1 decimal
Factor2 decimal
Factor3 decimal
Factor4 decimal
Factor5 decimal
Factor6 decimal
Factor7 decimal
Factor8 decimal
Factor9 decimal
IsGettingArchived   tinyint
```

Comment: Without any table definitions this is just guesswork. Please post details of your tables so we don't have to guess.

Comment: And just to expand on what @SeanLange said, we have no idea what the columns are in either table, because you didn't tell us that. [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: @EricBrandt updated question as requested by you and Sean. Thanks

Comment: Looking more closely now, I'm going to challenge your assertion that the first query you posted returns any columns from `tblConstituent`. It's only present in the correlated sub-query. In order for it's columns to be in the result set, it would have to be present in a `JOIN` of some kind.

Comment: Right off the bat your adding 2 more filter conditions in your subquery that were part of tblFamily  ; they are AND f.DataProviderID = 23 AND ISNULL(f.UsesIndexMarker, 0) = 0 . If your on time crunch use your first query and insert into a temp table or table variable and do a final select off of temp table/variable and pick out the columns you need.

Comment: what I'm saying is your adding the above 2 filters 2x . Once in tblFamily and a second time in your (new query) in tblConstituent.

Answer (score 3):

You are right Zeki Gumus.

But no need join equalevents below

```
    AND f.DataProviderID = 23
    AND ISNULL(f.UsesIndexMarker, 0) = 0
```

"where" exists them

Answer (score 1):

you can't put ListingId to list because you use tblConstituent with EXISTS instead of JOIN. Please check the following query, I believe this is what you want :

```
SELECT  F.FamilyID, 
        F.Name,
        F.DataProviderID,
        F.UsesIndexMarker,
        F.OpenDate,
        TC.ListingID
FROM    tblFamily AS f
INNER JOIN tblConstituent AS tc
                   ON tc.FamilyID = f.FamilyID
                     AND tc.StartDate < GETDATE()
                     AND tc.EndDate > GETDATE()
                     AND tc.FilterValue LIKE '%-%-%'
                     AND f.DataProviderID = 23
                     AND ISNULL(f.UsesIndexMarker, 0) = 0
```

I just noticed we don't need this part. Thanks Cagdas.

```
--WHERE DataProviderID = 23
--AND       ISNULL(F.UsesIndexMarker, 0) = 0
```